# How do I set an event listener for when a MediaElement.js video has ended, without having the video id?

Tags: javascript, html, video, addeventlistener

I need to set a listener for a video on SurveyGizmo that allows me to execute a function when the video ends. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="mejs-mediaelement">
    <video height="534" width="800" src="urlOfTheVideo" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>
```

so far I've tried to do this but it is not working:

```
<script>
function trailerEnd() {
  document.getElementByClassName('mejs-mediaelement').addEventListener('ended',alertThem);
  function alertThem(e) {
      alert('video has ended');
  };
};

trailerEnd();
```

Comment: There's multiple ways, depending on the case. You could, for example, use the method `getElementsByTagName` and then choose the n-th one in the array with `[n]`, or just get a close element or the parent element to the video and go from there. I just can't give you an exact answer with the information you provided.

Comment: Try this: `document.getElementsByClassName('megs-mediaelement')[0].getElementsByTagName('video')[0].addEventListener('ended',alertThem);`. If the parent element (div) is the first element with that class then it should work.

Comment: Also, you should probably declare the function `alertThem()` before adding the event listener, but I think that might still work anyways.

Comment: so I've tried to use your suggested code and it still has no effect for me `function alertThem() {
        alert('video has ended');
    };
document.getElementsByClassName('megs-mediaelement')[0].getE‌​lementsByTagName('vi‌​deo')[0].addEventLis‌​tener('ended',alertT‌​hem);`

Answer (score 0):

If `video` is immediate child element of `.megs-mediaelement` div, then you could select video element and add event to it like this.
mediaelement.js adds an extra wrapper around `video` tag, so using immediate child selector(`>`) won't work. Updated answer with decnendent selector. It should work now.

```js
var videoBlock = document.querySelector('.megs-mediaelement video');

videoBlock.addEventListener('ended', trailerEnd, false);

function trailerEnd(){
 console.log('video ended');
}
```

```html
<div class="megs-mediaelement">
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>  
</div>
```

Alternative you could also just select the video by using `var videoBlock = document.querySelector('video');` if there only one video on the page.

Comment: For some reason this code is not working for me either. Could it be something to do with the type of video player?

Comment: Based on the code you posted in your original question, on your code and my code both using html5 video tag, so both should be same video player. are you getting any error in console?

Comment: so I'm on survey gizmo and have limited access to what I can do. I can only add code to the source for each page of my survey. There is no console for me to print to.

Comment: what I meant is are you getting any error on browser's console, after applying code?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a jsfiddle with your code or the webpage you are working on, based on your question this should have worked, there might be some other information missing.

Comment: Sure, do you need all of the html from the site?

Comment: so quick update, this is using mediaelement.js which might change things.

Comment: I haven't had time to put together the jsfiddle to get that to you.

Comment: Please check updated answer, also here is a working jsbin with mediaelment.js https://jsbin.com/biducef/edit?html,js,output, hope this helps .